# .DS_Store "Changes not staged for commit?"

Tags: github, terminal, git-commit, git-add, git-repo

*I'm very new to coding so please be patient* On a macOs. I had help from a tutor to move my .ds_store and future .ds_store files into my .gitignore file, (wasn't aware what a .ds_store file even was until I accidentally uploaded it to a repo and had to delete it) but now I'm trying to add to a branch and I have two options come up in regards to the .ds_store file. Says:
Changes not staged for commit: (use "git add ..." to update what will be committed) or (use "git restore ..." to discard changes in working directory) modified: .DS_Store
no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
Now my question is- do I git add the file to update the changes to my local repo and push them to github? Or am I missing a step?

Haven't tried anything yet because I don't want to make a mess of the repo by adding and deleting a bunch of unnecessary files from the repo, im clueless at the moment.